# Saving json file overwriting data instead of adding

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js, fs

I created a `var data` where i read the json file through `fs` module.

So when i run a command `add <id>` command returns something like this

```js
data[message.channel.id] = channelData; 
return data;
```

which returns something like: `'channelid': { shows: [ 97938 ] }`.
And in message event i save to the json file like this:

```js
 const dataFile = "./data.json";
  const serverData = data[message.guild.id] || {};
if (cmd) const promise = cmd.run(client, message, serverData);   // not a promise just var name
    promise.then(ret => {
      if (ret) {
        data[message.guild.id] = ret;  // where ret is 'channelid': { shows: [ 97938 ] }
        fs.writeFileSync(dataFile, JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    });
```

Every time i run the command it saves something like:

```
{"guildid":{"guildid":{"channelid":{"shows":[97940]}},"channelid":{"shows":[97938]}}}
```

What I want to do is:

```
{"637301291068030997":{"689713983590105145":{"shows":[97938,97940]}}}
```

Comment: Could you please show your `cmd.run` function?

Comment: its already above other commands work so i skipped the cmd checking if it exists or other condition but `cmd.run` is already in given above

Comment: look where i defined `promise var`